# Remove spoofing email notifications

Tags: perl, spam-filter

I am using CentOS release 6.5 (Final) with MIMEdefang and I am getting spammed by someone that uses an e-mail spoofer. He sends alot of e-mails from random-user@mydomain to the same random-user@mydomain. I have set some SPAM rules on MIMEdefang so the messages are being rejected, but when they do, the random-user@mydomain receives a notification that the e-mail was marked as SPAM and it is getting really frustrating.

My question is how can I turn off the notifications for any-user_**@mydomain** so I dont receive the *Rejecting because of spam* email?
In my **/etc/mail/mimedefang-filter** I have the following code:

```
if ($hits >= $req) {`
  # We refuse spam over the max req score`
  md_graphdefang_log('spam_blocked', $hits, $RelayAddr);`
  md_syslog('warning', "Rejecting because of spam. Score: $hits ($names)");`
  action_bounce("Rejecting because message seems to be SPAM. Score: $hits ($names)., 554, 5.7.1);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the action to action_discard to just drop/discard the message instead of bounce it.

Comment: If I do that then MIMEdefang won't send any message back to e-mails that match my SPAM rule, and I could lose important data. I need to set action_discard only for all users @mydomain. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes - you could add an additional rule specific to this issue where messages from your local domain to your local domain higher than the expected spam score are matched and dropped. Are you expecting me to write your rules for you?